# Repaint doesn't work and the value of my private fields won't change?

Tags: java, netbeans, awt, paintcomponent, repaint

I am making a graphical interface in Netbeans where you can put a series of numbers (example: 7 8 5 4 10 13) in the textfield "punten" and when you press the button "ververs" a graphical linechart of all the numbers should appear (in my panel). I made a class "Gui" that extends JFrame with the Textfield, the button and a panel in it. I also made a class "Grafiek" that extends JPanel and that is linked with the panel in my "Gui".

The problems that I experience are: the repaint(); command won't go to the paintComponent(Graphics g)-method and my private variables won't change (the length of punt and punti stays 0).

Can somebody please help me, I've been working on this project for days.

My Gui-class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Gui() {
    initComponents();
    panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code"> 

private void initComponents() {

    punten = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    fout = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JButton ververs = new javax.swing.JButton();
    panel = new Grafiek();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    fout.setText("j");

    ververs.setText("Ververs");
    ververs.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            verversActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 195, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(punten, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(ververs)
                    .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                    .addComponent(fout)
                    .addGap(0, 302, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(punten, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fout)
                .addComponent(ververs))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void verversActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    Grafiek graf = new Grafiek();
    graf.verwerkData(punten.getText());
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel fout;
private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
private javax.swing.JTextField punten;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And my "Grafiek"-class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Grafiek extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private String[] punt;
private int[] punti;
private int afstandX, afstandY, puntX1=0, puntY1=0, puntX2=0, puntY2=0;
private int max=1;

/**
 * Creates new form Grafiek
 */
public Grafiek() {
    initComponents();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    try{
        for(int i=0; i<punti.length; i++) {
            if(max <= punti[i]) {
                max = punti[i];
            }
        }

        afstandX = getWidth()/punt.length;
        afstandY = getHeight()/max;

        for(int i=0; i<punti.length; i++) {
            puntX1 = puntX2;
            if(i == 0) {
                puntY1 = getHeight();
            }
            else puntY1 = puntY2;
            puntX2 += afstandX;
            puntY2 = getHeight() - punti[i]*afstandY;

            g.drawLine(puntX1, puntY1, puntX2, puntY2);
        }

        puntX2 = 0;
        puntY2 = 0;
    }catch(java.lang.NullPointerException npe) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}

public void verwerkData(String s) {
    punt = s.split(" ");

    punti = new int[punt.length];

    for(int i=0; i<punt.length; i++) {
        punti[i] = Integer.parseInt(punt[i]);
    }

    repaint();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work because you add your points to the wrong object.

First of all, your `panel` object is not of type `Grafiek`, second of all it is first initialized in the method `initComponents()` and then overwritten again in the constructor.

Second problem, in the method `verversActionPerformed` called by the action listener, you create a new instance of `Grafiek` that is obviously not the one you have created/added before.

Thus, to make it work alter the code as follows:

The constructor should look the following:

```
public Gui() {
    initComponents();
    //panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
}
```

The method like this:

```
private void verversActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    Grafiek graf = (Grafiek)panel;
    graf.verwerkData(punten.getText());
}
```

Thus, it works as you expected.

However, this is far away from good code. You should set the type of variable `panel` to the correct type `Grafiek`.